# Freestyle with panoramic camera

Tags: rendering, camera, freestyle, fisheye

I started using the panoramic camera, especially the fisheye equisolid, and upon trying to render a frame with freestyle, the lines are places as if the camera was still in the perspective lens type.
Is there any way to change this? Either in the compositor or other workspace.